# Change many-to-many association to one-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

`User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :partners
end
```

and `Partner`

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

and now, i want change it to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :partners
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

but how can i do it by migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the model's to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :partners
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And `Partner` model should have a `user_id` column

If you don't have a `user_id` column in `Partner` model, you can add it by:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_partner user_id:integer
```

The intermediate table `partners_users` should be dropped since it is a `has_many` Association.

To drop the table create an empty migration and then add this to the migration file.

```
drop_table :partners_users
```

Then run the migration using `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Tanks, but in my DB, i have a `partners-users` table for my many-to-many relation, and i want deleted it too.

Comment: Just remove the intermediate table `users_partners`. Nothing more to do.

Comment: but when i use `rake db:migrate`,  ‍‍‍‍‍‍`users_partners‍‍‍` comes back!